# there is a correct way to put a "title" for a fieldset inside a form?

Tags: html, dom, tags

Im new in this world of html, and my question is, if I have a form like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <fieldset id="f1">

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="f2">

            </fieldset>

            <fieldset id="f3">

            </fieldset>

</form>
```

and I want something like this

```
<form action="" method="post">
            **TITLE HERE FOR ID F1**
            <fieldset id="f1">

            </fieldset>
            **TITLE HERE FOR ID F2**
            <fieldset id="f2">

            </fieldset>
            **TITLE HERE FOR ID F2**
            <fieldset id="f3">

            </fieldset>

</form>
```

I know that there is a lot of ways to do it, but there exists a "correct way" to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an HTML `legend` tag just for that (and a few other use cases too). Here is how to use it:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>My title</legend>
  
  <input> <br>
  <input> <br> 
  <input> <br>


</fieldset>
```

Advantages:

- better for accessibility for example screen readers
- looks better because the fieldset's line breaks to allow the title to be emphasised.